# Does this change make a nonlinear differential equation into linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

is a non linear differential equation.

But if this read
[image]
then it would be linear.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right. Moreover, you can solve the second one just by integrating it twice.